# Render Twig Template instead of standard node fields

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

Right now my custom module creates a new content type. When an admin creates a node of that content type and save it they see the standard form elements displayed. However the custom module creates a controller/route: `path: '/directory/{name}'` and if the admin sets a URL alias on the node here is what happens:

- if directory is prepended in the URL path before the URL alias
- the controller is called, it finds the node via the alias
- and makes a couple API calls based on the values in the node
- And renders out a twig template with all the data is got from the API calls

What I want to happen is have the controller be called whenever a node of that content type is requested and my twig template to be rendered. So if a admin user created this content type and didn't set and alias, when they save and the browser directs them to /node/123 it will still call my controller and render my twig template. Or if an admin does set a URL alias, it will still call my controller and render my twig template.

Is there a way to complete this is Drupal?

---

Edit:

in my hook_theme I added:

```
      'node__campus_directory' => array(
        'base hook' => 'node',
      ),
```

And then I created a node--directory.html.twig file which is rendering. I now need some PHP function or to implement some hook where I can add some variables to be rendered in the twig template.

Comment: in the directory.module file I added:
```
      'node__campus_directory' => array(
        'base hook' => 'node',
      ),
```

And then I created a node--directory.html.twig file which is rendering. I now need some PHP function or implement some hook where I can add some variables to be rendered in the twig template.